# Displaying search results in ListView when amount of chars more then 3 in WinForms

Tags: c#, listview, sql-server-2008-r2

I've simple ListView with 3-4 columns which display list of clients. Below it there's a `TextBox` that is used to search in Sql Server and display related results (basically it executes `sql query` every single letter when typed. It was working fine with not much clients but with over 1000 typing one letter makes it hold display for about few seconds, display a lot of records, then another letter make it a bit quicker, and then another...

So I thought about couple of possible fixes to this:

- Start searching after typing 3 letters (the name has at least 3 chars), do nothing for 1st/2nd letter and display everything for 0 (still there's a delay when getting back from search)
- Load the list once to `List<string>` or create some kind of object to cover this, but I would need to keep it synced with any changes that is done by other users (adding new clients, updating names etc) from other work places and always update the list with proper information. Keeping it database related seems like an easier idea.
- Other ideas? Maybe combination of both?

Here's code sample:

```
   private void klienciSearchBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string varSzukaj = klienciSearchBox.Text.Trim();
        if (varSzukaj.Length >= 3) {
            pobierzDaneSqlKlientaOgolne(listViewKlienci, lvwColumnSorterKlienci, varSzukaj, radioButtonWyszukajPoPortfelu.Checked ? 1 : 0);
        } else if (varSzukaj.Length > 0 &&  varSzukaj.Length < 3) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            pobierzDaneSqlKlientaOgolne(listViewKlienci, lvwColumnSorterKlienci, varSzukaj, radioButtonWyszukajPoPortfelu.Checked ? 1 : 0);
    }
```

Is 1st or 2nd idea good enough or someone can propose other implementation?

Comment: I upvoted back to zero, this is a valid user interface scenario.  Not sure who downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar situation we handled this by limiting the number of results the user could get back.  We used a limit of 500 to keep things snappy and ran a count query prior to running the select query to check if it's about to pause the software.

It also depends if the problem is an unresponsive GUI or a wait for the user.  Since an unresponsive GUI can be fixed by running the query on a separate thread, you could then check if the query is running and cancel it when the user types the next letter.  Another option to prevent user waiting would be to display partial results.

Comment: It's a problem related to wait for results. Running a background thread is an option but the problem isn't that big since the results returned with 3 chars is like 5 or 10 so limiting the search from 3 chars up seems to be a good way. The only "slower" problem is when the user uses backspace and the list has to be populated with 1200 names so it takes 1-4 seconds but i guess having it like that one time only (per getting back from search) isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

The type of interface design that you currently have for searching is better suited for  data that updates infrequently.  For example, say you have a list of 10000 products that updates once a week, in this case, cache the data locally and then pull the data from the cache instead of the database for every letter typed.  That way it is one query to the DB and then many queries to the local cache.

In your case, data updates are more common, so I would change the interface to allow users to type in some letters, and then press a search button when they are ready to retrieve results.  As JamesB has noted, limiting the results back would also help but you are still hitting the database with a lot of queries.  If the users can live with some data latency, caching can be an option.  There is a lot of needless searching going to the database for "M" then "Ma" then "Mad" then "Madb" and so on...

Comment: The search button would also be an option. I'll ask users if they prefer the 1st option or button. Button would certainly limit searches